# PHP Can I define a variable protected variable inside class?

Tags: php, class, protected

In my class I want to declare a protected variable:

```
protected $subject = "Thank you for registering";
```

So far, so good. But when I want to include a variable I get an error:

```
protected $subject = "Thank you for registering on " . $nameOfWebsite;
protected $subject = $someVariable;
protected $subject = "Concated " . "String";
```

All return the same error, `syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';'`. Am I not allowed to do this? Why not?

Is there another way to make my protected variable variable?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is not allowed (and your examples don't make sense). Use a constructor, pass the value into it, and assign to the instance property (`$this->subject = $passedValue;`)

Comment: Out of those 3 code line, which line r u getting error?

Comment: @Sagar Please use proper English ("you" instead of "u", "are" instead of "r", etc).

Comment: Thanks @JonStirling! You too, @Rizier123, for pointing out the duplicate. Found an elaborate answer on what Jon said there.